# What are the names of the parts of leaves?

Tags: identification, leaves, terminology

When trying to identify or describe plants, it's helpful to be able to give specific details about the leaves. I know some of the basic shapes, but would like to learn what to call the different parts.

I'm hoping for a comprehensive description of each feature, including common and botanical terminology. Illustrations or links to pictures would be great too!

Comment: Might be a question for biology though this is also studied in horticulture

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: leaf layers]

[image: diagram]

[image: leaves]

[image: leaves]

[image: leaves]

Hope this is what you were looking for. These pictures are all from the site of the Colorado Master Gardener Program.   (There's much more extensive information there than I can copy here.) They have more diagrams, and the explanation are very good. You can also print them out:

http://www.cmg.colostate.edu/GardenNotesUpdate.shtml

This one gives definitions using examples of different leaves:

http://www.robinsonlibrary.com/science/botany/anatomy/leafparts.htm

This one is cute. You can test yourself after each section to see if you really get it:

http://www.botanical-online.com/lahojaangles.htm

Comment: Thanks Diane! This is truly excellent, what I was looking for and more. I'm sure all this work you've done will help a lot of people!

Comment: Sue- I'm glad! I can never remember all of the names, so I saved this post  to myself. Figured it  would be easier with the the diagrams in one place than having to look it up all the time.

Answer (score 4):

I think this question is too generic, so I'll give you a generic answer:

check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaf : it is very precise on terminology.